# XAMPP: Can't log in to MySQL (Cannot find authentication module: caching_sha2_password)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I started MySQL in the control panel of XAMPP, and I'm trying to log in to MySQL from the command line on Windows:

`C:/xampp/mysql/bin> mysql -u root -p pwd`

Getting this error:

`ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.`

Even running the command `mysql` gives this error.

I found other threads on SO that had the same error, and the solution was to go into `my.ini` config file and, under [mysqld] : add the line `default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password` to use a native password to authenticate. I saved the changes, restarted MySQL, tried to log in, and it's still giving me the same error.

What else could I try so I can log in?

Comment: You sure MySQL uses that ini file when you start it? And your sure you (correcly) saved the ini file?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have no clue how to check that. I just go to the console, click "Config" and open the ini file that it lists there. (It's the only ini listed)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Actually yes. I changed the port number in the same ini file I added that line to, and MySQL is now connecting through that port.

Comment: Well then check if MySQL maybe [loads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html) (see Table 4.1 Option Files Read on Windows Systems) more ini files which might overload the `default_authentication_plugin` again

Comment: @RaymondNijland For some reason theres no plugin folder to begin with. `C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugins` does not exist.. theres no lib folder. does that have to do with it? Also, that .ini file is the only one.

Comment: Iám out of options then, unless MySQLd starts with `--default-authentication-plugin=caching_sha2_password` as startup option.. and the ini never overloads it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I didn't realize, that I had MySQL installed somewhere else too. There was some kind of conflict with mysql in XAMPP and the previous mysql i installed it seems.. so i just uninstalled the old MySQL (this is version 8.0--maybe it was trying to connect to that one?). It works now:) I can log in to phpmyadmin and mysql. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if is too late, but you can solve doing two things:

1. In XAMPP's main menu, in config and inside my.ini add right after [mysqld]:

```
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

2. After installing MySQL Server you will have now in Windows MYSQL 8.0 Command Line Client. Once connected using your password write:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
```

Being the last root your new password.